# Where can I see dolphins in the sea near North-East China?

Tags: china, nature-and-wildlife, northeast-china

I have seen dolphins in Dalian Water Park but I want to see them in the sea at a particular time specially sometime before sunset.

Can anybody suggest me place in North-east China? Do they even exist in this part? It should be near Liaoning where I can travel within 5-7 hours on train.

Comment: To Chinese the "North-East" means just the provinces of Heilongjiang, Jilin, and Liaoning. Of those only Liaoning has a coast. But if you don't mean just the Chinese definition of "North-East" but the geographical northeast then you would probably include the provinces of Hebei, Shandong, and Jiangsu. But my Chinese friend who lives in Hebei province thinks the sea in this whole area might be too polluted to see dolphins ...

Comment: Well I meant It should be near Liaoning where I can travel within 5-7 hours on train. Not too far in the south. What do you mean by Whole ? Only Northeast or Whole coast of china ?

Comment: You should include all those relevant details in your question so people don't have to guess and don't have to ask for more details. One key principle of Stack Exchange is that if you expect people to put effort into good answers you should put effort into good questions. I don't know exactly what my friend meant be "whole" or if he knows much about dolphins. It's just a comment that's hopefully useful since I don't know enough for an actual answer sorry.

Comment: Well I tried my best to explain as in Norteast but anyways will try more to elaborate and Okay i got your point

Comment: Your edits still didn't add the information in your comment: `near Liaoning where I can travel within 5-7 hours on train` ... I'll add it in for you. People cannot be expected to sift through the comments for relevant info left out of the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are none to be seen from any regular organized dolphin watching tour. While there is an [aquarium in Dalian](http://www.laohutan.com.cn/) that has Dolphins, even those at least party [come from Japan](http://english.runsky.com/2008-11/28/content_2756139_2.htm).

Looking up [several sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_white_dolphin) for [population areas](http://www.cms.int/reports/small_cetaceans/data/L_obliquidens/L_obliquidens.htm) of [Dolphins](http://www.nmfs.noaa.gov/pr/pdfs/rangemaps/pacificwhitesideddolphin.pdf), you can discover that several species actually extend their territory to the coast of China, but all of them seem to avoid the area between South Korea and Shanghai and the subsequent Northwestern bay around Dalian and Beijing.

Even the [Indo-Pacific bottle-nose dolphin](http://maps.iucnredlist.org/map.html?id=41714) which is sometimes visible in [Jeju island](http://watashiwarika.blogspot.hk/2012/06/save-our-indo-pacific-bottlenose.html) of the south-western coast of Korea is endangered and does not come anywhere near Liaoning.